# I'm trying to create a character array where each line is a different word, however the "\n" in my do-while loop isn't working. I wonder why?

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, char, wordsearch

I have a college assignment in which I must create two matrices. The first works correctly, but this one is not recording each word on a different line. I already put NULL, "\0" and "\n" but none had effect.
Also, there is this message in the VSCode Editor: "comparison between pointer and integer (line 64, column 30".

I tried to create a matrix with a word in each line, this matrix will be used for word searches in the first matrix (which fortunately is working fine). To do that I created a do-while loop inside a for loop and in the scanf I put "\n" trying to make the program jump to the next line after the user press ENTER.
So guys, I need your help to understand what is the problem with my code...

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CHAR 20
int main(){
    int L, C, P, p=0;
    scanf("%d %d %d ", &L, &C, &P);
    char letras[MAX][MAX]; /*a matriz letras*/
    char palavras[P][CHAR];
    for(int p=0; p<P; p++){
        int c=0;
        do{
            scanf("%c", &palavras[p][c]);
            c++;
        }while(palavras[p][c]!= '\n');
    }
     return 0;
}
```

`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILMMn.png)

Comment: Please put your code in the question as text. There's not enough context in that screenshot to see what the problem is.

Comment: You need `'\n'`, not `"\n"`.

Comment: Yeah, double quotes for strings, single ones for characters. You seem to be indexing a character, so you need to compare to one.

Comment: You have incremented the index with `c++` *before* you make the comparison. So all bets are off.

Comment: You used `palavras[p][c]` for that, but further down (in commented-out code) you've passed `palavras[p]` for the `%c` specifier in `printf()`. I suspect there is a lot wrong with the code.

Comment: Is your compiler giving you any warnings that you are ignoring? If not, enable more warnings.

Comment: @pmacfarlane, They're not even at the compilation stage yet. They're still in the editor, which is giving the warning you talk about.

Comment: After `c++;`, test `c >= CHAR` and exit loop.

Comment: "but this one is not recording each word on a different line" is not evidenced.  There is no output.  Post a [mcve] with input used and output expected.

Comment: Needs more context. Create two matrices _of what_? Words? From where? What is the difference between the two? For what purpose?

Comment: Neil, I want to create two matrices with arrays of type char. My task is to build a wordsearch, for that the user has to insert N lines with letters and M lines with the words that the code needs to look for. On output the program will print whether the word is there or not.

Answer (score -1):

`"\n"` returns a pointer to the first of two characters. You want `'\n'` (the Line Feed character).